# Separate my Mysql Group Results

Tags: php, mysql

ok i have a list of results from my mysql database, basically it lists  the pages of my website viewed and groups them by date.   Now the results are fine and everything is grouped nicely.  and are displayed on the page like this.

29/03/2012 09:18   Page name

29/03/2012 09:24   Page Name

Now what i want to do is see if i can change the format so that the results are listed like this

29/03/2012

Page Name

Page Name

30/03/2012

Page Name

Page Name

one of the problems i have is that the date field is date time, though i could just strip the date out of the variable and use the date that way but i am not sure how to list the results as laid out above.  Below is my current code,

```
$query = "SELECT date, page_name FROM page_views GROUP BY date"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['date']. " - $". $row['page_name'];
echo "<br />";
```

Comment: Not particularly sure, but I suspect you're looking for either DATE() or DISTINCT.  Or maybe a combination.

Comment: Hi  Thanks i played with distinct but it seemed to just provide the same results as the current group query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use date() from PHP to format your datetime:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['date']));
    echo "<br />";
    echo $row['page_name'];
    echo "<br />"; 
}
```

this will result in:

29/03/2012

Page Name

30/03/2012

Page Name

Edit:

This is my only solution right now:

```
//First you select only the DISTINCT DATEs without TIME
$query1 = 'SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, %d/%m/%Y") as date FROM page_views';
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error()); 

//Create a while-loop to store DATE data in array
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $array[]['date'] = $row1['date']

    //SELECT the page_names where the date is LIKE the date in array
    $query2 = 'SELECT page_name FROM page_views WHERE date LIKE "%'.$row1['date'].'%"';
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());


    //Create a second while-loop to store the pagenames data in array who fits to the date
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) {
        $array[]['pagenames'][] = $row2['page_name'];
    }
}

print_r($array);
//This will output this:
$array = Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [date] => 29/03/2012
        [pagenames] => Array(
            [0] => pagename1
            [1] => pagename2
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [date] => 30/03/2012
        [pagenames] => Array(
            [0] => pagename1
            [1] => pagename2
        )
    )
)

//use foreach to display the data
foreach($array as $entry) {
    echo $entry['date'];
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($entry['pagenames'] as $pagename) {
        echo $pagename;
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have already done that, the problem is i have multiple pages for one date and so i want to list all the pages under one date, if that makes sense.

Comment: than you mustn't group your dates.
use `"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, %d/%m/%Y) as date, page_name FROM page_views"; `
than you will output only the date, not the time.
after this you need to update your while loop.

Comment: edited my answer with my solution. you can merge the foreach and while but with this solution you have an array where you can continue working with

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/track003/public_html/group_test4.php on line 20   which relates to line query 2

Comment: forgot the ; in the line before

Comment: OK thanks now i have the following  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/track003/public_html/group_test4.php on line 25  which refers to the open bracket on the second while loop

Comment: forgot the ) at the end of the while-loop ` while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {` instead of  `while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) {`

Comment: Thanks, that worked although it does seem like i have similar errors where the array section is, sorry i am a newbie and so a little out of my depth.

Comment: what array section? Don't write this in your code:
`print_r($array); 
//This will output this: 
$array = Array( 
    [0] => Array( 
        [date] => 29/03/2012 
        [pagenames] => Array( 
            [0] => pagename1 
            [1] => pagename2 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array( 
        [date] => 30/03/2012 
        [pagenames] => Array( 
            [0] => pagename1 
            [1] => pagename2 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
`

Comment: OK :) i did wonder but then i thought maybe it should be there, obviously not. ok one last thing i am getting an error for DATE_FOrmat so should that be changed to something else?

Comment: ok i change date format to date the results all group together but i get this error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/track003/public_html/group_test4.php on line 34

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(date, %d/%m/%Y") ` should be `DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d/%m/%Y") `. I forgot a " at the beggining of the dateformat (%d).

Comment: Hi Thanks Yes i noticed that and corrected it, but i now get the following error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/track003/public_html/group_test4.php on line 35  which relates to the second foreach statement

Comment: use `print_r($array); ` before the foreach and post the output here please